# Where do interest payments go?

Tags: interest

I understand that in many countries the base interest rates is set by a central bank. They do this by changing the amount they charge for overnight loans to the large banks to cover transfers. But when interest rates go up where does the additional money go?

Update: Obviously interest payments go to the lender. But the lender is paying higher rates to the central bank. What does the central bank do with them?

Comment: You take an auto loan today at **6%** from Really Big Bank.  Rates go up, and next week Bob takes an auto loan from Really Big Bank for **7%**.  Where does the extra 1% go?  To Really Big Bank, of course.  Why should Fed loans to banks be any different?

Comment: Another way of thinking about it is “who else but the lender *should* the extra interest payments go to?

Comment: I believe my answer addresses your update, and points to how you can follow it further if you want to. If that doesn't answer your question, you may be asking the wrong question.

Comment: Why does it matter that interest rates increased from 4% to 5%?  What’s so special about *that* rate hike as opposed to the 3% to 4% hike, or the 1% to 2% hike?  Ask instead what the central bank does with *all* of its interest payments.

Comment: I'm not American, I wasn't asking specifically about the Federal Reserve. This is a general question - in countries with a central bank that sets interest rates what happens to the additional payments?

Comment: You keep saying "additional".  Do you really mean "excess to expenses" (aka profit)?

Answer (score 5):

Interest payments go to whoever is making the loan.

Your interest payments go to your lender, the bank.

When the bank borrows money from the federal reserve, the interest goes to the federal reserve.

If the federal reserve makes an actual profit after operating costs, I believe that money goes back into the general budget, just as tax money does. In fact, the federal bank does publish income and expense data, eg https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/pressreleases/other20220114a.htm, which points out that "the Reserve Banks had estimated net income of $107.8 billion during 2021, of which $107.4 billion was remitted to the U.S. Treasury as required under the Federal Reserve Act."

So their profits, if any (and there aren't always) go to the Treasury. If you want to know what the Treasury does with money, you can get their statements too.

General-fund money goes where your representatives send it. Or at least it does if they don't then insist on withholding payments they already approved and trying to have it both ways.

Comment: The US FRB's profits are first [paid as dividends](https://www.federalreserve.gov/aboutthefed/section7.htm) on the stock that member banks are required to buy and hold. The rest is sent to the Treasury to pay down government debt.

Answer (score 1):

> Update: Obviously interest payments go to the lender. But the lender
> is paying higher rates to the central bank. What does the central bank
> do with them?

When a new auto loan is setup, the lender will charge a higher rate. They do this because not only do they have additional interest due to the federal reserve if they have to do any borrowing, but they also have to pay higher rates to their depositors. Their depositors expect this. In fact if they don't pay high enough rates some depositors will leave.

The central bank periodically transfers their profits to the general budget.